KL is an abelian extension implies K and L are abelian extensions

Prove of give a counterexample: If $KL$ is abelian then $K$ and $L$ are abelian.

I have proven the converse, that is if $K$ and $L$ are abelian then $KL$ is abelian. I have a feeling the above doens't hold, I have previously shown that the statement does not hold if we replace 'abelian' with 'Galois' by a counterexample. I have tried to use the same counterexample (where $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $L = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3})$), but $KL$ doesn't seem to be abelian in this case.
Any help is appreciated.

It's true. Let's use $F$ for the base field. If $KL$ is abelian, then in particular $KL$ is Galois, so $K$ and $L$ are separable. Because any subgroup of an abelian group is normal, $K$ and $L$ are even Galois. Now by Galois theory, $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F)=\mathrm{Gal}(KL/F)/\mathrm{Gal}(KL/L)$. A quotient of an abelian group is again abelian. The same argument holds for $K$.

Thanks! This is clear, I am curious though as to where the abelian property of the compositum comes in. Since if we take $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $L = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3})$, then $KL$ is Galois but $K$ is not. Or am I mistaken?

@JLGL For proving that $K$ and $L$ are Galois, the critical part is that any subgroup of an abelian group is normal. This is not true for general groups such as $S_3$ in your example.

Oh of course! Thank you.
